# What size wire will I need to feed a 3/4 hp pump?

Tags: electrical

I have a 230 v pump that will be 210 ft in the well and will be 820 ft from the house with a total of 1030 ft the pump is a 3/4 hp Gould pump What size wire will I need?

Comment: Is that 3/4 H.P. peak, or continuous?

Comment: More importantly, is it a 2-wire or 3-wire pump? In any case Gould's literature almost certainly has a chart detailing acceptable wire sizes; and @wallyk is right. A large aluminum feed to the wellhead and smaller copper wire down the well is going to be the practical answer.

Comment: WHY in the world is the pump SO far from the house???

Answer (score 1):

For a Goulds (CentriPro motor), 2-wire 3/4 HP submersible (5 FLA, 6.2 SFA) 8 AWG copper is [recommended for up to 1420 feet (5% drop) by CentriPro.](http://www.aquascience.net/resource/pdf/CentriPro-2-Wire-Motors.pdf) The chart is somewhat vague as to whether that's one way or round trip length; I'm sure you could call and ask, but 6GA is good for 2210, so 4Ga is clearly not required on that variant. Of course, I don't know that this motor is the one you have since you have not revealed your specific pump model.

Three wire motors require an additional wire, of course. Also an above-ground Start/run control-box. They also have higher amperage loads for the same power (6.6 FLA, 7.8 SFA). [8 Ga copper will only get you 1129 feet.](http://www.aquascience.net/resource/pdf/CentriPro-3-Wire-Motors.pdf)

If you have not yet purchased the pump, I'd strongly suggest the 2-wire version.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that length isn't trivial; that's for sure. Here's what I get...

> 3/4 hp = 6.9 Full load current (FLC) 
>  Wire size for that load no
> voltage drop (VD) = 14 AWG @ 125% (~9 A)

Limiting the circuit to 3% VD @ 1030 ft. I get...

> ## 4 AWG cu.

Comment: At that distance, it is almost certainly cost effective to run 1/0 aluminum and install a subpanel in the well head.  That way you can add lights and heat too.